# PySide - QTimer triggered socket.socket.recv() hangs

Tags: qt, sockets, tcp, pyside

I've built a simple PySide Gui application that is controlled by a `QObject` derived class. The class contains methods to connect to a tcp port and receive data. My plan is to have a `QTimer` trigger a `socket_read()` method that reads any input from the tcp socket and processes the data without blocking the main application.

So far I have the main app connecting to a tcp port successfully and a `QTimer` triggering a `socket_read()`. When `socket_read()` contains simple print statements the application keeps responsive and everything is fine but when I try to use `socket.socket.recv()` inside the method the method keeps on receiving data in a loop and running the code in that method but the rest of the app freezes.

Does anybody know what I'm dong wrong or what I need to do to keep the app responsive in this situation?

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
import socket

class AppController(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

        # socket
        self.socket_connection = None
        self.socket_listen_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.socket_listen_timer.timeout.connect(self.socket_read)


    def socket_connect(self, port):
        print 'connecting'
        host_name = 'localhost'
        socket_connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        socket_connection.bind((host_name, port))
        socket_connection.listen(1)
        self.socket_connection, addr = socket_connection.accept()
        self.main_window.console_info('Connected to {0}'.format(addr))
        self.socket_listen_timer.start(1000)


    def socket_disconnect(self):
        self.main_window.console_info('Disconnecting')
        self.socket_listen_timer.stop()
        if self.socket_connection is not None:
            self.socket_connection.close()


    def socket_read(self):
        print 'test'
        data = self.socket_connection.recv(1024)
        do_something_with_data(data)
```

Comment: I guess that because recv blocks until data is received, and no data is sent by the client? Are you familiar with python socket programming, see e.g. http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html? I'd suggest to use something else then polling each second, e.g. a QSocketNotifier, select(), separate threads etc.

Comment: Use a [QTcpSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpsocket.html). See the [Fortune Client example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneclient.html) in the Qt docs, and this PySide [example code](https://qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/source/060dca8e4b82f301dfb33a7182767eaf8ad3d024:examples/network/fortuneclient.py).

Comment: If you use Qt, why not use QtNetwork?